# Failed to set MoKListXRT: Out of Resources Couldn't create MoKLisTXR: Out of Resources ubuntu 21.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu

When I installed Ubuntu beside my main windows 8.1 this error shows when turn on my laptop:

[image]

The problem is that when i choose from menu boot Windows 8(it doesn't show as (windows 8) in menu boot but I choose HDD) / Ubuntu(it shows as Ubuntu in menu boot):

- when choose (HDD), this Error only shows, then nothing.
- when choose (Ubuntu) that i installed, it works after seconds from this Error.

I want choose from the 2 OS Windows 8 or Ubuntu but there is problem.

My laptop is a Lenovo Z580.
Please could you help me

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install?

Comment: i installed Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems with Windows are unrelated to Ubuntu.**

**Grub, the bootloader, can only boot working Windows.** What you should do now is try to boot Windows directly (UEFI settings > Boot) and if successful then let it install any pending updates and reboot how many times it needs. Then change the boot order back to Ubuntu, boot it and run `sudo update-grub` so it recognizes Windows correctly.

Meanwhile you may want to disable **Secure Boot** and **Fast Boot** in UEFI settings and also disabling **Fast Startup** in Windows is a MUST when dual-booting with this OS.

Comment: Please explain in steps and details cuz I'm begginer in Ubuntu, how to boot windows directly, windows doesn't work only Ubuntu that works, I entered in boot to disable secure boot but it's not allowed to change on it

Comment: How to boot Windows directly has NOTHING to do with Ubuntu. And how to do it depends on your specific hardware. As stated, it is generally found at UEFI ("BIOS") settings, "Boot" menu.

Comment: I already entered in bios but I don't know what's exactly should I do

Comment: You asked a question at an Ubuntu exclusive website about a Windows problem. Even so you got an answer explaining why it isn't related to Ubuntu and the basic steps anybody installing OSes should know in order to troubleshoot Windows and finally make the dual-boot work as expected. Everything IS in the answer. Can't you see a Boot menu where inside you can find the boot order? I won't repeat what is already in the question. If you aren't familiar with your own firmware you shouldn't be installing OSes.

Comment: If it isn't clear enough: When you finally boot Windows directly one of two situation will happen. (1) Windows boots normally (refer to the answer) (2) Windows doesn't boot which means it needs to be repaired or reinstalled, something obviously OFF-TOPIC here.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your explanation

Comment: Thanks the problem was in my windows Bios